# Добавить список стран в wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Надо в настройках wordpress темы (или в другом месте) дать возможность администраторам добавлять неограниченное число стран и ссылок с флагом для них. На front-end'е это должно выводится как выпадающий список со странами, при нажатии на одну из них пользователь переходит по указанной ссылке.

Answer (score 2):

Настройки темы описываются в файле `functions.php` данной конкретной темы. Если требуемый механизм реализовать в нём или отдельном файле и подключить его к `functions.php`, нужный функционал будет доступен на странице настроек темы.

В качестве альтернативы можно сделать соответствующий плагин. Хотя, не исключено, что есть и готовые плагины.